# How to create a WP theme that use BootStrap?

Tags: theme-development, templates, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am pretty new in WordPress and totally new in BootStrap development (I have beginning to study BootStrap yesterday) and I have the following doubt about how create a custom WP template that use BootStrap from 0.

For example I have the source of this page made using BootStrap: http://www.html.it/guide/img/bootstrap/demo/home.html

and I want try to create a WP template starting by it.

Some time ago I have realized a standard HTML\CSS template for WP, can I use the same tecnique dividing the previous page into (header, footer, content, etcetc) and the put in these section the WP php code to show articles and other WP functions?

Is it the right way?

The other doubts is related to the upper slideshow, in this slideshow the immage are fixed and definied in a static way:

```
<!-- Sezione slider con Flexslider -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
 <div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
   <li>
   <img src="assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg">
   <div class="flex-caption">
   <p class="flex-caption-text">
   <span>Lorem ipsum</span><br>
   <span>sit dolor</span><br>
   <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
   </p>
   </div>
   </li>
   <li>
   <img src="assets/img/flexslider/flex-2.jpg">
   <div class="flex-caption">
   <p class="flex-caption-text">
   <span>Lorem ipsum</span><br>
   <span>sit dolor</span><br>
   <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
   </p>
   </div>
   </li>
   <li>
   <img src="assets/img/flexslider/flex-3.jpg">
   <div class="flex-caption">
   <p class="flex-caption-text">
   <span>Lorem ipsum</span><br>
   <span>sit dolor</span><br>
   <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
   </p>
   </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div><!-- /.flexslider -->
```

And what can I do if I want that the administrator can choose the immages that should be displayed from the backend (I think in the theme configuration panel)

Can you give me some ideas about how do these things?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: There are some starter templates, integrating bootstrap, available, take a look at those to get inspired, for example [BootstrapWP](http://bootstrapwp.rachelbaker.me/) by @rachel-baker.

Comment: @ialocin what do you mean? to start from this BootStrap preconfiguried theme and then customize it?

Comment: Sure, you can customize one of the available ones. Or you can learn from the way others did what you want to achieve and most of the time it's best to dig into the code they wrote to do so. Basically, in short, what I meant is, if you're having trouble making your own, take a look at working ones to learn how to do it.

Comment: This question is far to broad for WPSE. You should perhaps start with the [Codex entry for Integrating WordPress into your Site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website), or the [Codex entry on Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development).

Comment: @AndreaNobili Take a look at http://wordpress.org/themes/the-bootstrap, download and learn code from it. That theme using Bootstrap.

Comment: @ucon89 this one seems use an old version of BootStrap, I want start using the last BootStrap verion...

Comment: @AndreaNobili oh, c'mon.. Even Bootstrap has a new version. You could learn from old bootstrap from that theme. The structure, how to code, css, WordPress Function, etc. Then, implemented your knowledge in a new theme and new version of Bootstrap. Stop asking question 'how to', because you know 'how to' do it. Do and learn from now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer your question, "How to create a WP theme that use BootStrap?"

Same like HTML/CSS like you have learnt before. You can implemented in WP theme.

Try to build a simple theme. Do not configure an admin panel if you do not understand how the front page works. But, if you want to know how to make an admin panel, here http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/a-guide-to-the-wordpress-theme-customizer-what-it-is-why-it-benefits-us/

I am happy if someone learn how to make WordPress Theme, It will make a plus for community. Learn and if you want to ask something, do not forget to put your code.

Happy code!